# create a symlink in an unprivileged container error

Tags: docker, permissions, containers, privileges, docker-entrypoint

I'm running K8s deployment and trying to harden the security of one of my pod and because of that I started using the following docker image:

nginxinc/nginx-unprivileged:alpine

The problem is that I need to create a symlink and cannot get it done.

Here is the structure of my dockerfile

```
FROM nginxinc/nginx-unprivileged:alpine

ARG name
ARG ver

USER root

COPY ./outbox/${name}-${ver}.tgz ./
COPY ./nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY ./mime.types /etc/nginx/mime.types
COPY ./about.md ./

RUN mv /${name}-${ver}.tgz /usr/share/nginx/html

WORKDIR /usr/share/nginx/html

RUN tar -zxf ${name}-${ver}.tgz \
  && mv ngdist/* . \
  && mv /about.md ./assets \
  && rm -fr ngdist web-ui-${ver}.tgz \
  && mkdir -p /tmp/reports

RUN chown -R 1001 /usr/share/nginx/html/

COPY ./entrypoint.sh.${name} /bin/entrypoint.sh

RUN chown 1001 /bin/entrypoint.sh

USER 1001

EXPOSE 8080

CMD [ "/bin/entrypoint.sh" ]
```

and here my entrypoint.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

ln -s /tmp/reports /usr/share/nginx/html/reports
```

and here is my container in the pod deployment yaml file

```
      containers:
      - name: web-ui
        image: "myimage"
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
          name: web-ui
        volumeMounts:
        - name: myvolume
          mountPath: /tmp/reports
```

I tried to set the entrypoint under the root execution but that did not help either, the error i'm getting is this:

> Error: failed to start container "web-ui": Error response from daemon:
> OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container
> process caused: exec: "/bin/entrypoint.sh": permission denied: unknown

Comment: Do you need to `RUN chmod +x /bin/entrypoint.sh`?  That error doesn't seem like it's related to the symlink at all.  You might try running the image with plain `docker run` before moving into the more complex Kubernetes environment (I think you're missing a `CMD` to run and an `exec "$@"` line to actually run it from the entrypoint script).

Comment: I have to admit, I did not create a test env because I thought it would be a very quick fix... Anyway, your suggestion to chmod worked, now i just need to fix the volumes and how they are mounted, but please post your comment as an answer and i'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like other Linux commands, a Docker container's main `CMD` can't run if the program it names isn't executable.

Most source-control systems will track whether or not a file is executable, and Docker `COPY` will preserve that permission bit.  So the best way to address this is to make the scripts executable on the host:

```sh
chmod +x entrypoint.sh.*
git add entrypoint.sh.*
git commit -m 'make entrypoint scripts executable'

docker-compose build
docker-compose up -d
```

If that's not an option, you can fix this up in the Dockerfile too.

```sh
COPY ./entrypoint.sh.${name} /bin/entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod 0755 /bin/entrypoint.sh
```

Like other things in `/bin`, the script should usually be owned by root, executable by everyone, and writable only by its owner; you do not generally want the application to have the ability to overwrite its own code.